# Opening a file on unit 5 or 6

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran77

I have a read/write operation going on in the Fortran code snippet as follows

```
OPEN(5,FILE='WKDAT.dat', STATUS='OLD')
OPEN(6,FILE='WKLST.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
```

I know that by default the unit number 5 is used for input from the keyboard and unit number 6 is used to display on the screen. Also I can use `*`.

But in the above-mentioned Fortran code unit number is 5 and a file name "WKDAT.dat" is given. So this means that the data is being read from "WKDAT.dat" file. Also there is code unit number 6 and a file name "WKLST.dat" is given. So this means that the data is being written to "WKLST.dat" file.
Is my understanding correct?

As per my basic knowledge: 
Unit number 5 is only used to take input from keyboard & unit number 6 is only used to print to console so no files should be involved. But in the code snippet it has both unit number 5, 6 as well as file name.

So both are contradicting :(

In this link http://www.oc.nps.edu/~bird/oc3030_online/fortran/io/io.html they have mentioned the following "When I/O is to a file you must ASSOCIATE a UNIT number (which you choose) with the FILENAME. Use any unit number other than 5 and 6. On some computers, some unit numbers are reserved for use by the computer operating system."

Comment: "Unit number 5 is only used to take input from keyboard ."... This assumption is wrong. 5 and 6 for Stdin and stdout is a historic practice in fortran, and most beginners book stress this practice. But.... Its just practice, not necessity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran has no magic unit numbers. The Fortran standard says nothing about 5, 6 or any other valid unit number being used for a special purpose. As such you are free to use the open statement to associate any valid unit number with a file. However traditionally for reasons that pre-date me 5 and 6 have been pre-associated with the keyboard and screen, as you say. Now still you can change the association by use of the open statement and that is fine save for the confusion it can cause, so most people I know recommend avoiding this and using unit numbers of 10 and upwards. Also because 5 and 6 are not guaranteed to be associated with the default input and output devices I would recommend against their use, preferring * or, in more modern code, the named constants `input_unit`, `output_unit` and `error_unit` from the `iso_fortran_env` intrinsic module.

So in summary you've got the right idea, and I'm not surprised you're confused.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in the standard says units `5` and `6` have any special meaning although in practice standard input and standard output are often *pre-connected* to 5 and 6.

Module `iso_fortran_env` from Fortran 2008 contains constants

```
INPUT_UNIT
OUTPUT_UNIT
ERROR_UNIT
```

with the unit numbers where standard input, standard output and standard error are connected. These are allowed to be different than 5 and 6.

Opening a file in unit that is in use causes the unit to be associated with the new file.

For example the [Cray Fortran manual](http://docs.cray.com/books/S-3695-35/html-S-3695-35/pdollsmg.html) says:

> Unit numbers 100, 101, and 102 are permanently associated with the
>   standard input, standard output, and standard error files,
>   respectively.

That means if you open some other file as unit `5` or `6` standard input and standard output still have some other unit where they are pre-connected and they will not be closed.

Comment: Am working with Fortran code that handles all I/O through C functions that use fcntl.h (i.e. file descriptors, not file pointers).  Would the 100-102 range be a problem in that case too?  Thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I have no idea. But possibly yes, they are pre-connected.