# Reading and overwriting same file

Tags: matrix, file-io, fortran, netcdf

So the goal of my code is to create a cumulative matrix from multiple NetCDF files. I want the code to check for an initial cumulative matrix(cp) that should be all 0.0s. if a matrix already exists, it gets the file and path from the command line and adds the values from the NetCDF file to to the end matrix.

```
! First loop creates an array in initalize.dat full of 0's if no file
    if (does_exist == 0) then
      open (unit=1, file=output_file, status='new')
      cp = 0.0
        do j = 1,168
          write(1, 10) (cp(i,j), i=1,77)
        enddo
      close(1)

10  format(1x, 77(f10.4))

! Since initalize.dat exists, we want to read it
    else
      open(unit=1, file=output_file, status='old', action='readwrite')
        do j = 1,168
          read(1,10) (cp(i,j), i=1,77)
        enddo
      RAINRATE = RAINRATE * 3600.0
      cp = cp + RAINRATE
        do j = 1,168
          write(1,10) (cp(i,j), i=1,77)
        enddo
      close(1)
    print *,"*** SUCCESS reading file ", input_file, "! "
    endif
```

The problem I am running into is replacing the values of the final matrix with the new values, after doing matrix addition. Instead of overwriting all the data, it adds it to the bottom of the data file (it should be 168 lines and it ends up being 336). I cant figure out what is causing this because I don't have a `position=append` anywhere. Some of the values in that array end up being negative as well, which is impossible since they're precipitation values.

Comment: Welcome. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention. Fortran 90 is just one old and obsolete version.

Comment: *"The problem I am running into is replacing the values of the final matrix with the new values, after doing matrix addition."* What sort of problem do you have with it?

Comment: @VladimirF Oh thanks, I am pretty new at the language. The problem I run into is that instead of overwriting all the data, it adds it to the bottom of the data file (it should be 168 lines and it ends up being 336). I cant figure out what is causing this because I don't have a position=append anywhere. Some of the values in that array end up being negative as well, which is impossible since they're precipitation values

Comment: Add the statement "rewind(1)" just after "cp=cp+rainrate"

Comment: @LexiAnderson The problem description belongs into the question.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to do a `rewind` on the file. Here's a little example:

```
program overwrite

    implicit none

    character(len=*), parameter :: f = 'matrix.txt'
    integer, parameter :: nrows = 4, ncols = 3
    character(len=*), parameter :: fmt = '(3I5)'
    integer :: u        ! Unit number of the file I/O
    logical :: f_exists ! Whether the file exists
    integer :: matrix(nrows, ncols) ! The actual data

    inquire(file=f, exist=f_exists)

    if ( f_exists ) then
        open(newunit = u, file = f, action='readwrite', &
            status='old', form='formatted')
        read(u, *) matrix  ! Reads values over multiple lines
                           ! until matrix is completely filled.
        rewind(u)
    else
        open(newunit = u, file = f, action='write', &
            status='new', form='formatted')
        matrix = 0
    end if

    matrix = matrix + 1
    write(u, fmt) matrix   ! Writes matrix 3 values per row (see the
                           ! format) until everything's written.

    close(u)

end program overwrite
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain what is happenning and clear your confusion.

> "I cant figure out what is causing this because I don't have a
>   position=append anywhere."

Well of course you don't have `position="append"` but that is irrelevant because you opened it before reading, not before writing. If you read the data, closed the file and opened it again for writing (best with `position="rewind"`, but it normally is not necessary), you would be writing at the beginning of the file and the old content woulld be overwritten.

```
  open(unit=1, file=output_file, status='old', action='read')
    do j = 1,168
      read(1,10) (cp(i,j), i=1,77)
    enddo
  close(1)
  RAINRATE = RAINRATE * 3600.0
  cp = cp + RAINRATE
  open(1, file=output_file, status='replace', action='write')
    do j = 1,168
      write(1,10) (cp(i,j), i=1,77)
    enddo
  close(1)
```

It has the advantage that you won't delete your data by mistake before reading it. I always feel unsafe when opening a file with some data with `action="readwrite"` or with no action explicitly specified.

BTW, don't use units smaller than 10, it is easy to hit a pre-connected unit. See [Why on Fortran code, one should use units bigger than 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277862/why-on-fortran-code-one-should-use-units-bigger-than-10) and [Opening a file on unit 5 or 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450692/opening-a-file-on-unit-5-or-6) . By far the best is to use `newunit=`.